# How to refresh SQL Server database table during runtime in Visual Studio-2010?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio-2010, datagrid

I am new to Visual Studio. I am working on a Visual Studio 2010 application in which I take the data from user, store it in a database table and display the same in datagrid in WPF.

But every time data entered into the table I have to close the application and click the `Execute SQL` right click menu option to refresh the table.

How to refresh the table at runtime so that the datagrid shows up-to-date entries?

Here is my save button click event method.

```
private void save_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


            string eid="", name, dept_txt, city, addr;           
            name = name_textBox.Text;
            addr = addr_textBox.Text;
            city = city_textBox.Text;
            //Object deptobj = dept_comboBox.SelectedItem;
            dept_txt = dept_comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim();
            dept_txt = dept_txt.Substring(dept_txt.LastIndexOf(":") + 1);
            eid = id_textBox.Text;


            //connection opeining.......
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:\\Users\\MYNAME\\Downloads\\VS projects\\employee-v1.2\\employee-v1.2\\Database1.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
            con.Open();
            string query = "insert into employee2(emp_id,emp_name,addr,dept,city) values('" + eid + "','" + name + "','" + addr + "','" + dept_txt + "','" + city + "')";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();
  }
```

What should I do to update the datagrid in runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me :

call this function whenever you want to reload the datagrid..

```
void fill_datagrid()
{
     string ConString = "YOUR CONNECTION STRING";

     string CmdString ;

     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);


     CmdString = "SELECT emp_id, emp_name from employee2";

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);

     SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

     DataTable dt = new DataTable("employee2");

     sda.Fill(dt);

     employee2DataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try mydatagrid.Items.Refresh();

Another option is to reload the datasource of your grid.

Comment: That didn't work.. My question is -How to refresh the table during runtime so that datagrid shows up-to-date entries?

Comment: So you want something which will watch if new data is entered in the SQL table and then refresh the datagrid?